# Angular *ngIf; else on async when undefined is a valid value from Observable

Tags: angular, loading

I am trying to use *ngIf; else on an observable which can emit undefined. Here is what I have

```
<span *ngIf="(content$ | async) as content; else loading">
  <span *ngIf="content != undefined; else notFound">
    // show content
  </span>
</span>
```

The problem is that if the value of observable is undefined, the page keeps showing #loading and doesnt switch to #notFound

Is there a way to accept undefined (can be changed to null) as a valid output value and get the UI to display the appropriate section at different stages?

Comment: Sound like you need another observable/subject to trace the `content$` is completed.

Comment: Of course it does, because `undefined` is falsy. On observable complete. you could set an other variable to whatever you want (or take a simple boolean) and check for this in the nested `ngIf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Boolean(undefined)` evaluates to `false`, the inner condition `content !== undefined` is always `true` and `notFound` will never load.

You will need to change your application logic.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle such scenarios seems to be using ngrxLet as such:

```
<ng-container *ngrxLet="content$ as content; suspenseTpl: loading">
    <span *ngIf="!content">
      <h2>Not found!</h2>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="content">
      {{ content }}
    </span>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
  Loading...
</ng-template>
```